# How to commit/compare/replace a file with SVN from MyEclipse 7.0?

Tags: java, svn, myeclipse

I am using MyEclipse 7.0 for the 1st time. Previously I was using MyEclipse 6.0. There I had option to commit file to SVN,compare a local file with SVN repository file,repalce a local file with SVN file. To do that I was going this way.

Right click on a particular file/project-->Team-->Synchronise with repository/commit.update.

But in MyEclipse 7.0 I am not getting option to do  this..Pls help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to MyEclipse > Manage pluggins and check for the subversive listed in the list there.

If it is not there then please upgrade to the lastest version of MyEclipse (7.1.1) and then open up the Dashboard by going to MyEclipse > Manage pluggins. You should see subversive listed in the list there. You can install it from there.

Once installed your problem will be resolved.

Hope this helps.